# Why requests are going twice in react?

Tags: reactjs, web

[image]

[image]

login request is sending twice .what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the request method, the first request has method OPTIONS, this is a "Preflight" request, which you can read about here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

It shouldn't actually execute your code assuming your routes are bound to a specific HTTP method, e.g., GET/POST